# WCF requires ISerializable constructor on abstract class

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm converting from Remoting to WCF. My code has a lot of optimisation in it to minimise the amount of data sent over the wire - consequently I am using ISerializable. As part of the upgrade I do not want to change to using built-in serialization - the work's been done so just want to continue to use it.

WCF will honour and use ISerializable however if I have an abstract class "fruit" which is marked as ISerializable and then concrete classes apple, banana and pear when WCF tries to do deserialize it complains:

"The constructor with parameters (SerializationInfo, StreamingContext) is not found in ISerializable type 'fruit'."

It doesn't need a constructor though! It's an *abstract* class and this constructor could only ever be called from a subclass: mybase.new(info,context). And my subclasses do not require that.

Why is it insisting on a constructor that will never be called?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to answer the question "Why is it insisting ..." but I did run into a similar problem (the need to create an abstract class for sending different obj definitions), and this is what I came up with.

I use a simple, basic class on both sides of the web service (host and client) as an input and output parameter. The class had only two parameters, a byte() param and a string parameter. Based on those two parameters, I could effectively send every imaginable data structure, wrapping any text or numeric data into the string parameter (as xml) and wrapping any byte data into the byte field of this class.

And since this "wrapping" is programmed, I can send an infinite number of different data objects from host-to-client, or client-to-host, without changing the web service interfaces ... the data and operation classes.

Every "method" exposed by the web service, from our simple Ping() function to our most complicated ResumeDownload() function, uses this same basic class for sending the bytes and params necessary to execute the function, and returning the results.

The basic class I use (pardon the VB) is below:

```
 Partial Public Class MessageStructure
     Inherits Object
     Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, IDisposable
     Private extensionDataField As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
     Private BodySectionField() As Byte
     Private TextSectionField As String

     Public Property ExtensionData() As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData
      Get
          Return Me.extensionDataField
      End Get
      Set(value As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject)
          Me.extensionDataField = value
      End Set
     End Property

     <DataMember(Order:=1)> _
     Public Property BodySection() As Byte()
       Get
         Return Me.BodySectionField
       End Get
       Set(value As Byte())
         Me.BodySectionField = value
       End Set
     End Property

     <DataMember(Order:=0)> _
     Public Property TextSection() As String
        Get
           Return Me.TextSectionField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
           Me.TextSectionField = value
        End Set
     End Property

     Public Sub New(ByVal text As String, ByVal Bytes As Byte())
        BodySectionField = Bytes
        TextSectionField = text
     End Sub
End Class
```

Hopefully, this helps you.